# Difference between javascript object literal notation and adding to objects

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain what is happening in the code below? I'd expect toString to get called for either both foo and bar, or neither.  How is literal object notation different from adding fields to an object after it is created?

```
function Obj(v) {
    this.v = v;    
};

Obj.prototype.toString= function() {
    window.alert("to string called for " +
                this.v);
    return this.v.toString();
}        

var foo = new Obj('foo');
var bar = new Obj('bar');

// toString is not called here.
var map = {foo : 'blah'};
// toString is called here.
map[bar] = "blah2";
```

Why do object literals not use toString() while adding to an existing object does use toString()?

http://jsfiddle.net/pByGJ/2/

Comment: You're misunderstanding prototypes if you're adding them every time the `Obj` constructor is called. You just add it once outside the constructor, and objects created from the constructor will have automatic access to it.

Comment: ...the object created using object literal syntax will clearly not inherit anything from the `Obj` constructor's prototype. It only inherits from `Object.prototype`, not every other custom constructor you defined.

Comment: @user1689607 I believe you're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @will Replace the declarations of `foo` and `bar` with `var foo = 'var_foo'; var bar = 'var_bar';` (instead of `new Obj('...')`), rerun the code and you'll understand what's happening here.

Comment: okay changed the question so I don't keep changing the prototype, but the root of the question renames the same.

Comment: @NullUserException: You're right, I misunderstood. It's basically a different take on the common *'how do I use a variable as a property name'* question.

Comment: @NullUserException If foo and bar are strings, they get quietly added to map.  I still don't entirely understand why this different  var map = {}; map[foo] = 'foo';

from this
var map = {foo: 'foo'}

Comment: @NullUserException I don't see what you mean, care to explain in an answer? I think you may also be understanding what the question is asking, the OP expects `toString` to be called in the first example because they thing `var map = {foo : 'blah'};` is using `foo` the variable to create the name of the property

Comment: @NullUserException Maybe you mean use `var foo = new Obj('fooName'), bar = new Obj('barName') ` and realize that the object will not end up as `{fooName: 'blah', barName: 'blah2'}`

Comment: @JuanMendes It was an example meant to show `map[aVar]` and `map = { notVar: thing }` are different things. Using strings instead of the custom object simplifies the example.

Comment: @will The `foo` in `var map = {foo: 'foo'}` is a not interpreted as a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason that object literals don't evaluate the identifier to the left of the colon is so you're not force to quote all literal names (as you do in JSON).

Bracket notation forces you to quote property names, if you don't, it will be evaluated as a variable.

The reason `toString()` does get called in the second example is because `bar` has to be converted to a string to be used as a property name.

In your first example, you're just creating a literal object (that is the exactly the same as  `{"foo" : 'blah'}`). So that is never using the variable `foo`

If you want to create an object using a variable name, you can't use literal object notation, you have to use `[]` which is what forces it to call `toString()`

Here's a function to create objects with variable names in one expression.

```
function obj(key, value /*, key, value, ... */) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0, ln = arguments.length ; i < ln; i+=2) {
        obj[arguments[i]] = arguments[i+1];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

## Clearer Example

The fact that your variable names and values are the same doesn't help understanding the problem. Let me suggest this code

```
var foo = new Obj('fooValue');
var bar = new Obj('barValue');

var map = {foo : 'blah'};
map[bar] = "blah2";

// You expect map to be {fooValue: 'blah', barValue: 'blah2'}
// But it's {foo: 'blah', barValue: 'blah2'}
```

To do what you need, use my `obj` function

```
// Almost as clear as literal notation ???
var map = obj(
    foo, 'blah',
    bar, 'blah2'
);
// map = {fooValue: 'blah', barValue: 'blah2'} Yay!!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Editing my question so it is more clear.

I'm curious why object literals don't use toString(), but [] forces toString()

Comment: @will Updated the answer to make it clear that literal property names don't get evaluated so you don't have to quote them.

Answer (score 2):

keys in an object literal are taken as strings, not interpreted as variables. This:

```
var map = {foo : 'blah'};
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var map = {"foo" : 'blah'};
```

and this:

```
var map = {};
map["foo"] = "blah";
```

but is completely different than this:

```
var map = {};
map[foo] = "blah";
```